# What are the effects on signal detection metrics when a base rate matching strategy is used?

Tags: signal-detection

Assume that:

- We have two groups of observers
- The base rate of the signal being present is 97%
- Knowledge of this base rate is provided to observers in the second group

Group descriptions...

1. tends to fail to detect the signal, and so they only say that the signal is present 60% of the time.
2. tends to fail to detect the signal as often as the first group. But, they adjust their strategy to artifically make the proportion of time they say the signal is present match the known base rate.

What would we expect with regards to d' values and bias values for these groups?

My intuition was that the 2nd group would eliminate their bias, but that the d' of the two groups would otherwise be equal.  However, my attempts at simulating the outcome have been indicating that group 2 has higher d' relative to group 1 and that their bias is similar.  I'm assuming this is an error in my simulation - but I wanted to check here to see if perhaps it is my intuition that is flawed rather than my code.

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting caught up in the words that are used, e.g. sensitivity index, and bias... and they aren't the underlying thing itself but an attempt to measure the thing?

Comment: Interestingly, to me at least, group 2 seems to end up with a lower A'.

Comment: How do you define $d^\prime$ and how do you simulate it? Possibly there is a discrepancy between the two concepts that you apply. Is your $d^\prime$ a property of the distributions of the signal and noise or a property of the detection method?

Comment: d' is calculated as you describe below.  I think that d' is interpreted as a combination of the characteristics of the signal, the noise, and the reciever.

Comment: In my sim I did not use raw signal and noise distributions, just the judgement (based on known TPR) and the base rate matching rule.

Comment: What sort of simulation do you do? Why do you believe that your simulation should keep the d' the same when you apply the changes from group 1 to group 2? ------ Could you explain both these questions such that the background of your problem is clear. Your issue is that you expect d' to remain the same but in your simulation it doesn't. It is difficult to answer to this question in detail. This is because it is not strange for the d' to change, so it is difficult to understand what your question is about when there is no clear idea why it should be expected that d' does not change.

Comment: If d' measured the sensitivity of the observer, and the observer just applied a base rate matching rule - then their sensitivity is no better for applying the rule.

Comment: ... but, d' doesn't measure the sensitivity of the observer or necessarily even the relationship between real signal and noise distributions... which I think is the lesson learned in all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the sensitivity from z-scores of true positive rate and false positive rates.

$$d^\prime = zTPR - zFPR$$

But this remains only equal (independent from the classification boundary) when the noise and signal are distributed with equal variance.

The noise and signal may easily have a different variance. For instance when the signal is some variable with variance and noise added to it, then it has a higher variance than the noise.

Comment: Is there anything about base rate matching that should be construed as creating inequality between the signal and noise distributions?

Comment: @russelpierce base rate matching is (I guess) done by using a different decision boundary. This different decision boundary changes the TPR and FPR values. The distributions can remain the same.

Comment: Awarding the bounty to this answer.  This particular answer didn't help, but the answerer helped me think through the problem elsewhere in the comments and that's good enough for the reward in my book.